# NetCut Defender slow Internet speed

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10

Recently I installed netcut defender, ever since then my wifi speed drops to 20-30 Kb/s when netcut is closed but again shoots up to 150 Kb/s(max) as soon as it is
enabled. Uninstalling netcut defender and winpcap has no effect. Is there any way I can remove netcut defender and regain my original speed ?

Comment: So if its installed but not running the speed is fine?

Comment: @Ramhound No, it has to be running for the speed to be fine.

Comment: Follow this [guide](http://tunderscore.blogspot.com/2013/11/how-to-uninstall-netcut-defender.html) in the future don't install hostile software by choice.  The reputation on Netcut is absolutely horrible

Comment: @Ramhound Tried almost all guides in the internet including the one you mentioned but none of them help.